# Matlab. How to draw image

Tags: image, matlab

I have one function, which returns vector with data. I should draw an image depending on this data.

For simplify let's consider this example: function returns [4, 10, 3], so I should draw 10 x 3 rectangle and 4 circles around this rectangle. Also I need save this image to file, but this isn't necessarily.

There's so much different functions for drawing/plotting, so I can't understand what I should use.

I'm using matlab 2013a, if it matter.

Would be grateful for any articles/code snippets for this task.

Comment: Look at `rectangle` in the help. Also good for drawing circles. I'm not joking.

Comment: Does your function always return an array such as `[a, b, c]` where `a` is the number of circles, `b and c` the size of a rectangle or might it return also dat for, say, draw a pentagon? In the case of your question, where the position of the rectangle is specified (it seems you have only width and lenght). What about the centre and the radius o the circles?

Comment: Yes, function always return a correct array.

Comment: Position of rectangle -- center of image, radius of circles -- predefined constant. For example 1. Same about center, for example half of circles -- leftward from rectangle with some predefined constant, and other half -- rightward from rectangle.

Comment: @nkjt - LOL @ I'm not joking... because you really can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Look at `rectangle` in the help. Also good for drawing circles. I'm not joking.

This is exactly what I looked for.